# EXCEL listing out all numbers in a range?

Tags: excel

Excel version 1907

Given the first column, i would like a function to produce the 2nd column

```
004-005 | (004|005)
006-007 | (006|007)
009     | (009)
010-046 | (010|011|012|013|014|015...045|046)
```

Currently doing this manually, but it's just not scalable

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: @ScottCraner 1907

Comment: Create a [UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-overview).

Answer (score 2):

If you have Office 365 Excel, You can use TEXTJOIN as an array formula:

```
="("&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,TEXT(ROW(INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,--LEFT(A1,3)):INDEX($ZZ:$ZZ,--RIGHT(A1,3))),"000"))&")"
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If one does not have Office 365 this udf mimics that functionality.

```
Function TEXTJOIN(delim As String, skipblank As Boolean, arr)
    Dim d As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim arr2()
    Dim t As Long, y As Long
    t = -1
    y = -1
    If TypeName(arr) = "Range" Then
        arr2 = arr.Value
    Else
        arr2 = arr
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    t = UBound(arr2, 2)
    y = UBound(arr2, 1)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If t >= 0 And y >= 0 Then
        For c = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 1)
            For d = LBound(arr2, 1) To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr2(c, d) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c, d) & delim
                End If
            Next d
        Next c
    Else
        For c = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
            If arr2(c) <> "" Or Not skipblank Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & arr2(c) & delim
            End If
        Next c
    End If
    TEXTJOIN = Left(TEXTJOIN, Len(TEXTJOIN) - Len(delim))
End Function
```

Put that in a module and use the formula as described above.

Comment: congrats btw!  Just seen